# how to filter list base on another list in kotlin/java?

Tags: list, filter, kotlin

I have two types `FooApi` and `FooModel`:

```
class FooApi (var aId) 
class FooModel(var mId)
```

Is a way to simplify below function which filter `FooModel` list base on `FooApi` list:

```
fun f(fooModelList: List<FooModel>, fooApiList: List<FooApi>) : List<FooModel> {
  return fooModelList.filter { fooApiList.map { it.aId }.contains ( it.mId ) }
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It looks ok to me. I would only change some minor things (not required though), so that it ends up something like the following:

```
 fun List<FooModel>.f(fooApiList: List<FooApi>) = filter { m -> fooApiList.any { it.aId == m.mId } }
```

Some reasons why I did it this way:

- I think that filtering is always applied on a list of `FooModel`s, right? (that is the reason for the extension function narrowing the type to `List<FooModel>`)
- You are not interested in the mapped object of fooApiList, so that is why I used `any` instead; the nice benefit there also is that now both values that are compared are next to each other
- summarizing everything can be said so easily, you can even omit the method body (and therefore return type, return statement, etc.)

Still, that's nearly the same as you did already... Just a bit less code and a rearrangement... Calling it by the way would look like:

```
val listA : List<FooModel> = TODO()
val listB : List<FooApi> = TODO()

val containedList = listA.f(listB)
```

If you require such a construct more often, maybe the following more generic solution is helpful:

```
fun <T, U> List<T>.intersect(uList: List<U>, filterPredicate : (T, U) -> Boolean) = filter { m -> uList.any { filterPredicate(m, it)} }
```

Which you can then also use like:

```
val containedList = listA.intersect(listB) {
    a, b -> a.aId == b.mId
}
```

Then your `f` again might even look just like:

```
fun List<FooModel>.f(fooApiList: List<FooApi>) = intersect(fooApiList) { a, b ->  a.mId == b.aId }
```

Comment: This is not working if I use != . Is there a way to use with it?

Comment: The intersect extension function. Maybe is mandatory to use filterNot?

Comment: But then it isn't really an intersection, is it?

Comment: Yeah, I wrote a new function with filterNot called difference (it is the same, only changes filter to filterNot). You can add it to your reply if you want so it can help to more people!

Comment: I am using my smartphone at the moment, with which it isn't that easy to edit ;-) I am not so sure whether I would really use `filterNot .. any .. != `.. that sounds a bit complicated to me.. I'll look on Monday ;-)

Comment: Ah no, it is filterNot and ==. It is the contrary behavior of Intersect. In my case with Intersect, I am getting the correct answers from a list, with Difference, I am getting the wrong answers.

Comment: Ok.. that sounds better... Confused it with your initial `!=`-comment :-) I would probably still go with `filter` here and use `none` instead...

Comment: the problem is `filter` with `!=` is not working, it isn't the difference, to get the real difference we have to use `filterNot` and `==`. BTW if you can test it should be great to avoid using two functions.

Comment: Can test it on Monday.. you have two function calls nonetheless.. `filterNot..any.. ==` or `filter..none..==` should make no difference..

Answer (score 11):

I would do something like

```
val apiList = listOf(FooApi(1), FooApi(2), FooApi(3))
val modelList = listOf(FooModel(1), FooModel(3))

val output = apiList.flatMap { api -> modelList.filter { api.id == it.id }}
```

Givin as output

> [FooModel(id=1), FooModel(id=3)]

I don't know if the difference is significant...

Comment: Flatmapping models to api won't produce a list of models. Switch the variables.

Comment: @EugenPechanec Oops of course. Answer edited, thanks.